# Finding an average SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, average

im trying to create an average on a rating.

i have tried the AVG(column_name).  however the problem with this is it does a total for all the ratings and gives the average.

```
Select Company.company_id, company.Company_Name, avg(UserJobRating.Total_Rating)
from company
inner join UserJobRating on Job_id = UserJobRating.Job_ID
inner join jobs on jobs.Company_id = company.company_id
group by company.company_id
```

what i want is say for example, a spefic company has 10/15 jobs each with a job rating. i want it to group together the jobs specific to that company and give an average rating for the company over all their jobs.

what type of select would i need to do in order to do this?

Comment: You need a group by clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to guess a little bit on what's going on from your comment, so I think your `JOIN` is off a bit.  Try this:

```
Select Company.company_id, company.Company_Name, avg(UserJobRating.Total_Rating)
from company
  inner join jobs on jobs.Company_id = company.company_id
  inner join UserJobRating on jobs.Job_id = UserJobRating.Job_ID
group by company.company_id
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6466c/2)

Without seeing your table definitions, this is a bit of a guess, but I would bet you're producing a `Cartesian Product` with the `UserJobRating` table with this statement:

`on Job_id = UserJobRating.Job_ID`

Comment: yeah man that was it... what did you do to change it? all i can see what is different is the order in the inner joins

Comment: @AndrewGlass -- you need to reference the `jobs.job_id` field when joining on the `userjobrating` table.  Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the `join` condition:

```
Select Company.company_id, company.Company_Name, avg(UserJobRating.Total_Rating)
from company
inner join UserJobRating on Job_id = UserJobRating.Job_ID
----------------------------^
inner join jobs on jobs.Company_id = company.company_id
group by company.company_id
```

What is happening is that `company` does not have a field called `Job_id`.  So, this condition is really:

```
inner join UserJobRating on UserJobRating.Job_id = UserJobRating.Job_ID
```

Which, is essentially, a `cross join` rather than an `inner join` (the only difference is that this would filter out `NULL` values of `job_id`).

Presumably, the proper field is in the next table, so you need to rearrange the tables in the join:

```
Select Company.company_id, company.Company_Name, avg(UserJobRating.Total_Rating)
from company
inner join jobs on jobs.Company_id = company.company_id
inner join UserJobRating on jobs.Job_id = UserJobRating.Job_ID
group by company.company_id;
```

This should solve your problem.